# Podfile.lock No such file or directory

Tags: ios, typescript, firebase, cocoapods

In firebase nativescript ,I have complete all of the steps which was given and push notification it was working for the Android.

In iOS app when I was trying to put the app in to itunesconnect it's popping up errors. But the App it runs on the simulator itself for "tns run ios" in terminal.

[image]

It says update pods, But when I ran the pod install this message pops up

[image]

After the pod Install error stays the same.
Anyone have a solution (xcode v8.1, tns-ios@2.4.0)..

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/263

I got it worked. Just needs to type --release."tns prepare ios --release".

Answer (score 0):

This is a build configuration issue. Select the project and go to Info tab.
You see Configurations outline tab.  Both Debug and Release must be "No Configuration Set".  If you see "1 Configuration Set", some other configuration is selected.  If so, open Debug and Release configuration outlines and select "None".

Now no configurations are selected.  Go to the command line and type "pod install"

You won't get error message in the command line and you are ready to build.